# Thread causes applications to become unreponsive

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have an activity which registers an Observer using the following code

Activity:

```
//Register for network status updates
NetworkStatus networkStatus = new NetworkStatus(this);
networkStatus.addObserver(new OfflineActivity());
Thread thread = new Thread(networkStatus);
thread.run();
```

Subject:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    for(;;) {
        Log.d("NetworkStatus", "Checking Network Status");
        if(isConnectedToInternet(context)){
            notifyObservers();
            Log.d("NetworkStatus", "Network Connection is established");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("NetworkStatus", "Not connected to network");
        }
    }   
}
```

When I click into the activity, the program becomes unresponsive.. Any ideas?

Comment: Umm, infinite loop generating notifyObservers() messages when connected to internet?

Comment: I had a thread.sleep() but I removed it because I thought that it was causing the problem. The problem was thread.run() instead of thread.start().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `.start();`

```
Thread thread = new Thread(networkStatus);
thread.start();
```

when you explictly call the run method, it doesn't actually spawn a new Thread, instead the method call still runs in the UI Thread.

Comment: Ah of course, been making mistakes like this all day, thank you (again :P)!

Comment: No problem :-) Keep in mind though that multithreading had potential to severely fail. Make sure to be careful!

Answer (score 2):

Your Thread run is in infinite for loop. Please add break condition, so that it can exit.